# BigQuery "view is self-referencing"?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two views. Each runs fine alone; i.e.

`select * from x` ...and... `select * from y`

But when I run

```
select * from x join y using (a,b)
```

I get:

```
Error: View project.z is self-referencing.
Job ID: project:bquijob_36210f49_15c3d9bce56
```

I'm sure that `z` isn't self-referencing, because even when I change it to reference a single table, I still get this error.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Are the views defined over a wildcard table with a filter on _TABLE_SUFFIX? What I've seen in the past is that this error can happen if the wildcard includes the name of the view itself.

Comment: Right, but if that were the case then the error would occur regardless of the join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this: Google Support let me know they identified the issue and will release a fix soon